# How to configure log4j2 in Weblogic 12c?

Tags: java, weblogic, slf4j, log4j2, weblogic12c

in a web application we used log4j2 (2.0.1 version) and slf4j. We want to print application logs to a different log file. We configured log4j2.xml file for this purpose and it works at Tomcat. When we deploy the application to Weblogic 12c, application works but it doesn't print any log to log file. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: You may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734503/prevent-weblogic-12c-from-using-systems-slf4j-binding

Comment: The link Paul mentioned should help - do you see any slf4j log messages in your server's .out file? There is not enough information here to help without guessing