# How to write OCI JAVA SDK logs into Weblogic Server log files

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

Here I am using Weblogic 12c Server to deploy my web application. In my application I'm using OCI JAVA SDK to interact with Oracle Cloud Infrastructure(OCI) Service. As per the documentation by OCI, "OCI JAVA SDK" is using SLF4J logging. So that I've bundled "slf4j-jdk14-1.7.23.jar" JAR file in my ear file. Still I was not able to see the OCI SDK generated logs in the weblogic log files.

I've added the below entries in weblogic-application.xml as well:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>


<!-- if not using prefer-application-resources you will get a warning like this: -->
<!-- Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings -->
<!-- SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/wls1211/modules/org.slf4j.jdk14_1.6.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] -->
<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```

After adding the above entries, "StaticLoggerBinder" class not found errors are resolved. But still not able to see the SDK generated log statements in weblogic log files.

Am I missing any specific configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Weblogic, but I tried configuring "JDK14"-style logging from the command line, hoping that it will help you.

As an example, I'm using [PaginationExample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/PaginationExample.java), which is in the `examples` directory of the `oci-java-sdk.zip` file that you can download from the [releases page](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/releases).

I have unpacked the `oci-java-sdk.zip` file, changed into the `examples` directory and compiled the `PaginationExample.java` file:

```
cd oci-java-sdk/examples
javac -cp "../lib/oci-java-sdk-full-1.2.38.jar:../third-party/lib/*" PaginationExample.java
```

Now I have a `PaginationExample.class` file in the current directory.

I also downloaded the [slf4j-1.7.23.zip](https://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.7.23.zip) file and unpacked it. For me, the JDK logging bridge file is `../../slf4j-1.7.23/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.23.jar`.

I can now write a `logging.properties` file to configure JDK14 logging, e.g.:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$s [%1$tc]: %5$s%n
```

Now I can run the example using:

`java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -cp ../lib/oci-java-sdk-full-1.2.38.jar:../third-party/lib/*:../../slf4j-1.7.23/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.23.jar:. PaginationExample <tenancy ocid>`

With the above `logging.properties` file, output, down to the `FINE` level (which is `DEBUG` in slf4j terminology) goes both to console and to a file.

This works on the command line. It sounds like WebLogic is using the JDK14 `java.util.logging` framework, and we need to get slf4j to feed into that. You're already doing what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734503/prevent-weblogic-12c-from-using-systems-slf4j-binding).

Since the above configuration works for console and file, I'm wondering if the [server logging bridge](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLLOG/logging_services.htm#WLLOG200
) isn't configured correctly.

This page seems to describe how to do that: http://buttso.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-slf4j-with-weblogic-server.html